# MATLAB: A .(dot) operator

Tags: matlab

I have to interpret the following MATLAB code:

```
load('pmat.mat');
vecP = pmat.pmat;
```

I have no clue for how 'pmat.mat' looks like. I wonder what the dot(.) operator does. I applied that to a vector, and it returns an error.

```
>> x=[1 2 3]

x =

 1     2     3

>> x.x
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's for a matlab [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html).

For example,

```
>> x = struct('a', 4, 'b', [1 2 3]);
>> x.a
4
```

Answer (score 1):

It thinks you're trying to reference the field named x of a struct named x, but you get an error because the array x is not a structure.